# How to access http status in Azure Function v4

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, http-status-codes, azure-http-trigger

How do i read the http status of a http trigger function built using Azure Functions v4?

The equivalent in v3 would have been something like

const statusCode = context.res.status;
context.log(`HTTP Status Code: ${statusCode}`);

I've tried debugging and trying to find the status amongst the context variables but i understand it's not there. I can see from the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-node-upgrade-v4?tabs=v3) that you can set the status using a return status e.g. return { status: 200 }; but i don't know how to simply read the current status.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How do i read the http status of a http trigger function built using Azure Functions v4?

I have created a Http triggered function.

**code:**

```js
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const name = request.query.get('name') || (await request.text()) || 'world';

        // Your response object
        const response = { body: `Hello, ${name}!` };

        // Log the HTTP status code
        context.log(`HTTP Status Code: ${response.status || 200}`); // Default to 200 if not set explicitly

        return response;
    }
});
```

The above code executed successfully.
**Output status in Local:**

[image]

I have successfully deployed the http trigger function into Azure portal. check below:

[image]

Then click on the function, go to `code+test`, and run the code. It runs successfully, and the status is below:
**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Apologies as i'm pretty new to this but in your example you're setting the status to 200 and then reading it afterwards aren't you? 
What i'm trying to achieve is letting the API determine the status and then reading that. Also, i'm using Javascript, again this seems very easy to do in AZ Functions v3 with 'context.res.status' but i can't seem to do it using v4?

Comment: @ReoDude, I updated the above as javascript . AFAIK, I searched about `context.res.status`
status code without setting in code manually its not possible in function v4 got statement like `The Azure Functions team is aware of the need for a way to directly access the HTTP status of a function execution in v4. They are planning to add this feature in a future release`.

Comment: That's interesting to hear this feature is not yet in v4. I'm looking into the possibility of using APIM Policies instead to read the status set by the runtime and set a custom response.
Thanks for your efforts.